# Pythonic way of finding differences between two strings

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
a = "3030104AF43B000A3F1D200619D09FE00403031324354650004FFFFF"
b = "3030104BE3B000C3DF1D200617183BA00403030335F5B6F0004FFFFF"
```

Let's say `a` and `b` are two hexadecimal string values of which are equal and even in length. They also share the same format such that differences occurring between both strings always happen at the same position (But, initially I do not know which position these differences occur). For example `a`'s first six digits are the same as `b`'s first six digits. i.e., `303010`. The following 4 digits are different `4AF43B` in `a` compared with `b`, after which the next two digit are the same for `a` and `b` (`00`). This pattern follows on until the end of both strings.

I have written code to store the differences occurring as different elements in a `list`.

```
seed = "3030104AF43B000A3F1D200619D09FE00403031324354650004FFFFF"
seed2 = "3030104BE3B000C3DF1D200617183BA00403030335F5B6F0004FFFFF"
seed = seed.rstrip("FF")
seed2 = seed2.rstrip("FF")
differences_list1 = []
differences_list2 = []
sequence1 = ""
sequence2 = ""
for pair in range(int(len(seed) / 2)):
    data_pair1 = seed[pair * 2:(pair * 2) + 2]
    data_pair2 = seed2[pair * 2:(pair * 2) + 2]
    if data_pair1 == data_pair2:
        if sequence1 == "" and sequence2 == "":
            continue

        # here, we know it is not an empty sequence
        differences_list1.append(sequence1)
        differences_list2.append(sequence2)
        sequence1 = ""
        sequence2 = ""
        continue

    # when they are not equal to each other
    sequence1 = sequence1 + data_pair1
    sequence2 = sequence2 + data_pair2

print(str(differences_list1))
print(str(differences_list2))
```

Output (which I want):

```
['4AF43B', '0A3F', '19D09FE0', '1324354650']
['4BE3B0', 'C3DF', '17183BA0', '0335F5B6F0']
```

I've gotten the output as I desired somehow but I would like to know how can I improve/write my code in a more pythonic way (specifically python3.9)?

Comment: You should ask this over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would start by looking at the `difflib` module.